# How to create array of object from table td?

Tags: javascript

How can I create an array of objects fromthe table excluding the header

How can I create object like this `let list = [{name:'James',id='1'},{name:'Johnson',id:'2'}]`

here is my  javascript which wrote but the error here is it adds table header too and for select that is dropdown it does not add the selected value ? What changes should i make so that it should give desired output

```js
const list = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('table tr')).map(({
  children
}) => ({
  name: children[0].textContent,
  id: children[1].textContent
}))

console.log(list)
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="size">2</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name="plan" id="plan">
          <option value="Cook">Cook</option>
          <option value="James" selected>James</option>
          <option value="professional">Professional</option>
          <option value="corporate">Corporate</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Have valid HTML
2. Check if you have something with a value or not

```js
const list = [...document.querySelectorAll('table tbody tr')].map(row => {
  const name = row.cells[0].firstElementChild
  return {
    name: name ? name.value : row.cells[0].textContent,
    id: row.cells[1].textContent
  }
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(list))
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="size">2</p>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>id</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select name="plan" id="plan">
            <option value="Cook">Cook</option>
            <option value="James" selected>James</option>
            <option value="professional">Professional</option>
            <option value="corporate">Corporate</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Johnson</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```